# How to create directories in a secure way in python

Tags: python, bash, security

I'm faced with the following problem:

The users have some files that need syncing so I'm writing a script that copies the encrypted files from a user's directory to a temporary directory in the server before it gets distributed in the other 5 servers.

The initial copy is done by creating a folder with the user's name and putting the files there.
The users are free to change usernames so if someone changes his username to something nasty the server(s) is/are owned

I have to use the usernames for folder names because the script that does the syncing is using the folder username for metadata of some sort.

So, is there any way to escape the usernames and make sure that everything is created under the master folder?

Comment: Generally, this stuff is handled by permissions at the OS level ... Are you running the script as root?

Comment: The best way to prevent issues is to make use of `realpath`, I am not sure how it is done in Python/Bash, but in php and `basepath` in perl can be used to verify that no directory traversal is occurring

Comment: @mgilson I don't know the permissions the script is going to be called with, that's why I'd like to make it as foolproof as I can

Comment: `os.chroot(base_of_your_directory_structure)`

Comment: Either the script will run with user permissions, or the project you are writing it for is in a huge deep trouble, security-wise.

Comment: You may want to clean up the question rather than adding an explanation below the confusing part.

Answer (score 1):

As nrathaus suggested you could use os.path.normpath to get "normalized" path and check for security issues